# Using Lambda expressions with Dictionaries

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I try get data from DB and insert to Dictionary

The data like:(column from DB) Email.Email and have (column from DB)error message Invalid email

(column from DB)Email.Required (column from DB) error message This field is required

I want create Dictionary looks like

```
Dictionary<string , Dictionary<string,string>>
```

And result be:

```
<Email, <Email, Invalid email>
<Email, < Required, This field is required>
```

I start do:

```
 Email = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>()
            {
                {
                   data.Where(k => k.Key.Contains("Email."))
                       .Select( k => k.Key.Split(new string[] { "." }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0])
                       .FirstOrDefault(),new Dictionary<string, string>()
                   {

                       {
                         data.Where(k => k.Key.Contains("Email."))
                          .Select( k => k.Key.Split(new string[] { "." }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1])
                          .FirstOrDefault(),
                          "VALUE"
                       }
                   }
                }
            }
```

The result I get looks like

```
<Email,<Required,value>>
```

but I don't success to take

```
 <Email,<Email,value>>
```

Edit:

data looks like:

[value data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ubR2.png)

I don't get exception because I have only one "Email" and this key I have Dictionary that I stores the value

***My solution ***

```
    Email = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>()
            {
                {
                   _dataFromDB.Where(k => k.Key.Contains("Email.")).Select( k => k.Key.Split(new string[] { "." }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0]).FirstOrDefault(),
                   _dataFromDB.Where(k=> k.Key.Contains("Email.")).ToDictionary( k => split(k.Key) , va => va.Value )
                }
            }


    private string split(String key)
    {
        string[] values = key.Split(new string[] { "." },   StringSplitOptions.None);

        return values[1];
    }
```

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Eszw.png)

Comment: My data looks like 

Dictionary<string, string> data 

<Email.Required, this field is required>
<Email.Email,Invalid email>

Comment: I don't get Exception because I enter the value to Dictionary have only one key with "Email"

Comment: what´s the content of data?

Answer (score 0):

You cant have this

> And result be:

```
<Email, <Email, Invalid email>
<Email, < Required, This field is required>
```

Since the Dictionary allows unique keys only

What you can do is this:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string , Dictionary<string,string>>
```

And then add what you want in the list using

```
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,Dictionary<string,string>>("Email", dictionary here));
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you write, your data looks something like what can be represented by the following array:

```
var data = new [] {
    new { Col1 = "Email.Email",  Col2 = "Invalid email" },
    new { Col1 = "Email.Required", Col2 = "This field is required" },
};
```

You will need to use a group by to get all rows which need to be in the 'inner' directory.

To get the structure you want you can use the following code

```
var results = (
    from row in data.Select(x => new { Key1 = x.Col1.Split('.')[0], Key2 = x.Col1.Split('.')[1], Col2 = x.Col2 })
    group row by row.Key1 into g
    select new { Key = g.Key, Value = g.ToDictionary(k => k.Key2, v => v.Col2) }
)
.ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Value);
```